# Unity3D : How to flash a collectible icon and text on screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please have a look on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgAagJgyMBQ&feature=youtu.be&t=41s)  video.

At 45 seconds the **COD Ghost icon flashes with text** beneath it. 
I would like to achieve same for my game .
I am a beginner and i think slowing down video shows this that its getting scaled.So Transform and some particle system may have been applied for splash effect .But there are many other sequence of animation occurring in video on icon.

Comment: Did you even try anything? Do you have a code that is not working?

Comment: @Programmer I am a beginner , i dont have any idea how to accomplish this.I have done splashing sparks behind text for this using Particle system but that is just 1 thing from what i want.

Comment: Not a great excuse. At-least you should mention where you are having problem. As a beginner here you go http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting

Comment: @Programmer thanks for the link , after studying i will update my answer .I hope you can then help me with this task

Comment: Ok. I went ahead and provided an answer since your are learning. Test it when you get time.

Comment: @Programmer From that link i was able to show a Label and Texture with flashing text upto now, but your answer is so smooth and awesome .I am gonna test it soon .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these can be done from script. From watching that video, these are the steps to follow in order to replicate that effect:

**1**.Image Appears (Enable Image)

Make the image very big then slowly scale it down.

**2**.Wait for `0.3` second

**3**.Text Appears (Enable Text)

Make the text very big then slowly scale it down. You can do this by changing the font from a big number to a small number.

**4**.Wait for `1` second

**5**.Blink text `4` times by toggling the alpha value of the Text (`Color.a`) to `0` and `1`. Alpha `0` is invisible and `1` is visible. Wait for  `0.1` second after each toggle. You can do this in a `for` loop.

**6**.Text Disappears(Disable Text)

**7**.Wait for `0.3` second

**8**.Image Scales down then disappears
Get the size of the image then divide it into 2.
Scale to to that value over time.

While scaling it, change the alpha of the image from 1 to 0. This will
gradually make it invisible.

Now Disable the image. That's it.

*I made a code for this and you can modify it to add particles after step **#3**. Below is what it looks like*:

[image]

To use the code:

Create a **UI Text** by going to **GameObject**->**UI**->**Text**.

Create the **UI Image** that will display on the Screen by going to **GameObject**->**UI**->**Image**.

Put the text under the image.

Change your text settings to match the circled text properties in red from the image below. When you are done modifying both `Text` and `Image` components, disable them so that they are not visible before running the code.

Attach the Script to the `Canvas` then drag the text to the `textToAnimate` slot in the script. Drag the image to the `imageToAnimate` slot in the script.

[image]

Below is a complete code to do this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textToAnimate;
    public Image imageToAnimate;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CODGhostEffect(textToAnimate, imageToAnimate));
    }

    private IEnumerator CODGhostEffect(Text text, Image image)
    {
        //Step 1 Enable Image
        image.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        Color defaultTextColor = text.color;

        Color invisibleTextColor = text.color;
        invisibleTextColor.a = 0; //Set Alpha to 0

        //Image RectTransform
        RectTransform imageRect = image.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        Vector2 defaultImageSize = Vector2.zero;
        defaultImageSize = imageRect.sizeDelta;

        //Make the size of the Image to be 5x bigger then scale it back to be original size over time
        Vector2 scaledImageSize = defaultImageSize * 5;
        imageRect.sizeDelta = scaledImageSize; //Set the image size to be 5x 
        float imageAppearTime = 0.3f;
        float counter = 0;
        while (counter < imageAppearTime)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            float time = counter / imageAppearTime;

            //Scale the image back to the original Size size OverTime 
            imageRect.sizeDelta = Vector2.Lerp(scaledImageSize, defaultImageSize, time);
            yield return null;
        }

        //Step 2 Wait for 0.3 Seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);


        //Step 3 Enable Text
        text.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        //Make the font size of the Text to be 4x bigger then scale it back to be original size over time
        int defaultTextSize = text.fontSize;
        int scaledTextSize = defaultTextSize * 4;
        text.fontSize = scaledTextSize; //Set the text font size to be 4x 

        float textAppearTime = 0.2f;
        counter = 0;
        while (counter < imageAppearTime)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            float time = counter / textAppearTime;

            //Scale the text font size back to the original Size  OverTime 
            text.fontSize = (int)Mathf.Lerp(scaledTextSize, defaultTextSize, time);
            yield return null;
        }

        //Step 4 Wait for 1 Seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);

        float textBlinkTime = 0.1f; //Time between blinking Text
        WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(textBlinkTime);

        //Step 5 Blink Text
        /////////////////////////Flash Text/////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            //Hide Text by setting alpha to 0
            text.color = invisibleTextColor;

            yield return waitTime; //Wait 

            //Show Text by setting alpha to defaultvalue
            text.color = defaultTextColor;

            yield return waitTime; //again 
        }

        //Step 6 Disable Text
        text.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        //Reset text color to default color
        text.color = defaultTextColor;

        /////////////////////////SLOWLY MAKE Image DISAPPEAR/////////////////////////
        Color defaultImageColor = image.color;
        Color invisibleImageColor = image.color;
        invisibleImageColor.a = 0; //Set Alpha to 0


        Vector2 halfImageSize = Vector2.zero;
        halfImageSize = defaultImageSize / 2;

        //Step 7 Wait for 3 Seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

        //Step 8 Animate Image disappearance
        float imageDisappearTime = 0.2f; //How long to hide the UI Image (0.2 seconds)
        counter = 0;
        while (counter < imageDisappearTime)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            float time = counter / imageDisappearTime;

            //Scale to half size OverTime 
            imageRect.sizeDelta = Vector2.Lerp(defaultImageSize, halfImageSize, time);

            //Fade OverTime
            image.color = Color.Lerp(defaultImageColor, invisibleImageColor, time);
            yield return null;
        }

        //Disable Image
        image.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        //Reset image size to default size
        imageRect.sizeDelta = defaultImageSize;

        //Reset image color to default color
        image.color = defaultImageColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Softxide Remember, If it doesn't work, you did something  wrong because I put an image of it working. I works on my side perfectly fine. Here is a UI tutorial if you are stuck anywhere http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: its working like a charm , thanks,  i will continue experimenting and will be in touch in future too

Comment: @Softxide You are welcome. The steps in the codes are commented to   match the steps in the answer. So you can easily modify it and add other effects such as blur and particles.

Comment: i understood everything in script but why we needed horizontal and vertical overflow  in inspector ?

Comment: @Softxide So that the texts will always fit and show on the screen. If you don't do that and you change the font of your text to a very big number, the text will be cut out. It wont show. If you set it to overflow, it will automatically resize the RectTransform of the text to fit the whole text no matter what font size you have. The only way to understand is to try it your self. Set that to something else then try to resize the font to a bigger number. The text will disappear